# Implementing interfaces by inheritances

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a common interface that many classes in my project inherit (FWIW it's a ref-counting interface). This interface is inherited by both classes and other interfaces. Instead of re-implementing the interface in every class, I'd like to just have a corresponding implementation class that all the other classes inherit. The problem is the way I have it laid out leads to a diamond-of-death.

```
struct IBar {
    virtual VOID Bar() = 0;
};

struct CBar : IBar { // implementation class for IBar
    VOID Bar() { }
};

struct IFooBar : IBar {
    virtual VOID Foo() = 0;
};

struct CFooBar : IFooBar, CBar { // implementation of IFooBar interface
    VOID Foo() { }
    // Bar() should be implemented by the inheritance of CBar
};
```

If I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error C2259: 'CFooBar' : cannot instantiate abstract class
1>          due to following members:
1>          'void IBar::Bar(void)' : is abstract
```

I realize I can fix this by implementing `CFooBar::Bar() { return CBar::Bar(); }` or having `IFooBar` inherit from `CBar` but I suspect there's a less hacky way of solving this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try always [virtually inheriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) from IBar. That way, you cut out the middleman, so to speak, and always directly inherit from it regardless if you also inherit from one of its decendents.

Eg:

```
class IBar {
    public:
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
};

class CBar : public virtual IBar { // implementation class for IBar
    public:
    void Bar() { printf("bar\n");}
};

class IFooBar : public virtual IBar {
    public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
};

class CFooBar : public IFooBar, public CBar { // implementation of IFooBar interface
    public:
    void Foo() { }
    // Bar() should be implemented by the inheritance of CBar
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CFooBar cfb;

    cfb.Bar( );

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'd always recommend using `class` over `struct` if you are writing any member functions - such a thing is, after all, by definition a class. Also, it's worth explicitly setting access modifiers as in my example (the above code doesn't actually compile without adding them).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a `using CBar::Bar;` declaration?